# How can I select and index the highest value in each group of a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with multiple columns, each combination of columns describing one experiment (e.g. multiple super-labels, for each super-label multiple episodes with different number of timesteps). I want to set the last timestep in each episode for all experiments to True, but I can't figure out how to do this. I have tried three different approaches, all using `.loc` and 1) using `.max().index`, 2) `.idxmax()` and 3) `.tail(1).index`, but they all fail (the first two with for me ununderstandable exceptions and the last one being wrong.

This is my minimal example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(4)
def gen(t):
    results = []
    for episode_id, episode in enumerate(range(np.random.randint(2, 4))):
        for i in range(np.random.randint(2, 6)):
            results.append(
                {
                    "episode": episode_id,
                    "timestep": i,
                    "t": t,
                }
            )
    return pd.DataFrame(results)

df = pd.concat([gen("a"), gen("b")])

base_groups = ["t", "episode"]

df["last_timestep"] = False

print("Expected:")
print(df.groupby(base_groups).timestep.max())

#df.loc[df.groupby(base_groups).timestep.max().index, "last_timestep"] = True
#df.loc[df.groupby(base_groups).timestep.idxmax(), "last_timestep"] = True
df.loc[df.groupby(base_groups).tail(1).index, "last_timestep"] = True

print("Is:")
print(df[df.last_timestep])
```

The output of `df.groupby(base_groups).timestep.max()` is exactly what I expect, the correct rows are selected:

```
Expected:
t  episode
a  0          3
   1          4
b  0          2
   1          1
   2          4
```

But when filtering the dataframe, this is what I get:

```
Is:
   episode  timestep  t  last_timestep
2        0         2  a           True
3        0         3  a           True
4        1         0  a           True
8        1         4  a           True
2        0         2  b           True
3        1         0  b           True
4        1         1  b           True
8        2         3  b           True
9        2         4  b           True
```

The rows 0, 2, 5 and 7 should not be selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) for repeat max aggregated values and compare by column `timestep`:

```
df["last_timestep"] = df.groupby(base_groups)['timestep'].transform(max).eq(df['timestep'])
print (df)
   episode  timestep  t  last_timestep
0        0         0  a          False
1        0         1  a          False
2        0         2  a          False
3        0         3  a           True
4        1         0  a          False
5        1         1  a          False
6        1         2  a          False
7        1         3  a          False
8        1         4  a           True
0        0         0  b          False
1        0         1  b          False
2        0         2  b           True
3        1         0  b          False
4        1         1  b           True
5        2         0  b          False
6        2         1  b          False
7        2         2  b          False
8        2         3  b          False
9        2         4  b           True
```